# Why are there returns in my string value?

Tags: html, angularjs

So in angular 1.5.x I have an array like so.
I am using this array to filter a list that I get back from my DB but thats working great. For filtering I used this resource https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter.

Now when I use it my list goes blank. So I decided to see why. The reason why is because my yes and no when selected all of a sudden set my filterFilter.prop to:

> "↵                                    Yes↵                                "

If anyone knows why please let me know.

Otherwise I might just do a trim on ng-change but my question is why are the returns there and how do i remove them without doing a trim on ng-change?

P.S. as soon as I remove the returns then the filter works properly. but I put no returns in the array below.

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module("mainApp");
var controller = function($scope){
  $scope.decs = [null,"Yes", "No"];

 };

    app.controller("controller ", ["$scope", controller]);

}());
```

and I display on the frontend like so

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
    <select ng-model="filterFilter.prop">
       <option ng-repeat="dec in decs">
          {{dec}}
       </option>

    </select>
/*additional html*/
</div>
```

Comment: You say `like so` but this implies you show us your code, but you have not shown us your code which constructs your array. Please **edit** and update your question.

Comment: Why? because you aren't using `value` on option. When no value is set, browsers uses text but you have extra whitespace in your text when you break it into multiple lines. Open and close the option on same line with no extra whitespace and will see different result. Using `value` is preferred approach

Comment: @charlietfl that was the missing piece thankyou. dont know how that slipped through. preciate it. :)